# Displaying my own error messages for system calls

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, system-calls

So I have this beginner's assignment problem which requires me to make some system calls using already present executables. I just need to fork and call `execvp` for simple commands like `ls` and `cat`. The problem is that I also need to display a custom error for incorrect commands (like `cat a.txt` even though a.txt doesn't exist) and further, display the normal error messages these commands show.

Second part is very easy, `execvp` would automatically ensure that the program prints its normal error messages. My problem is that I don't know how to detect whether `execvp` has run into some error. How do I print out my own error message before the executable of `ls` shows its own error message?

Comment: [Redirecting exec output to a buffer or file](//stackoverflow.com/q/2605130). Also, check the return code from the program.

Comment: Have you looked at the `execvp` [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)? It discusses the return value of the function call and the `errno` variable. This and your course material should be enough information to solve your task.

Comment: Some commands when they fail will exit with a specific value. You can retreive that exit value with the `wait` function from the parent process, and if it's an "error" you can print your message. For what values a program might exit with, reads its manual page.

Comment: *Before*? Hmm. You'd have to capture the ls process' standard error, wait for it to exit, check its exit status for success or not, and display the appropriate output.